# Generate all possible hex bytes in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, hex, byte

I'm trying to generate all possible hex bytes and set them to a byte string. This is,

I have this:

```
iv = b"\x14\x42\x31\xB5\xFE\x52\xA3\x32\x3E\xEA\xA4\x30\x00\x11\x23\xFE"
```

And for instance, I want to try all possible values for byte 7:

```
b"\x14\x42\x31\xB5\xFE\x52\xA3\ + x00\ + x3E\xEA\xA4\x30\x00\x11\x23\xFE"

b"\x14\x42\x31\xB5\xFE\x52\xA3\ + x01\ + x3E\xEA\xA4\x30\x00\x11\x23\xFE" 

b"\x14\x42\x31\xB5\xFE\x52\xA3\ + x02\ + x3E\xEA\xA4\x30\x00\x11\x23\xFE"

(...)

b"\x14\x42\x31\xB5\xFE\x52\xA3\ + xFF\ + x3E\xEA\xA4\x30\x00\x11\x23\xFE"
```

How can I iterate and manipulate these structures in python?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for loop`

```py
all_combination = []
for i in range(256):  
    all_combination.append(iv[:7] + bytes([i]) + iv[8:])
```

```
[b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x00\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x01\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x02\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x03\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x04\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x05\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x06\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x07\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x08\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\t\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\n\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x0b\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x0c\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\r\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x0e\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfe\x0f\xa32>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe'
.
.
.
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfeR\xa3\xfd>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfeR\xa3\xfe>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe',
 b'\x14B1\xb5\xfeR\xa3\xff>\xea\xa40\x00\x11#\xfe']
```

Comment: I thought that was not working because of the print results. Now I see they are formatted to be output but the inner data is still correct. Fantastic!

Comment: yes, you are correct. the bytes are represented in character